# How to restore activites with saved instance state

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to save and restore my users details when the activity is destroyed. I have searched for a while but i try the code yet it doesn't work. The code looks correct but it still does not work. When my activity is destroyed and i create it again it does not show me what i saved.
Here is the XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.gigabytedevelopersinc.savedpractice.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type here"
    android:id="@+id/txtone"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="150sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90sp"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:saveEnabled="true"/>


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Java

```
 package com.gigabytedevelopersinc.savedpractice;

 import android.os.PersistableBundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText firstEdit;
private String storeFirst = "STORE_FIRST";
private String editstore ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firstEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtone);


}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    firstEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtone);


    outState.putString(storeFirst,firstEdit.getText().toString());


}

     @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    firstEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtone);

    firstEdit.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(storeFirst));



     }
 }
```

Comment: Did you try restoring from `onCreate`?

Comment: Yes i have tried it. It still does not work

Comment: Try removing the argument `PersistableBundle outPersistentState` from the signature of `onSaveInstanceState` and the call to `super`

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Hmm... This is weird... Technically, you should not have to save the instance state of an `EditText`. It should be done by your `Activity` without you doing anything. If the instance state of your `EditText` is lost, it means either the instance of the `Activity` is a different one, or you set its text in your activity somewhere that conflicts with the state being restored

Comment: I didn't set it's text but i set a hint. Does that affect it